# Web Player playback for Ampache

Tags: browser, playback

Is there any way to add to Ampache the ability to playback audio files directly from a web browser without the need to use a local media player? Or do you have any other server-side music streaming program to recommend, with such capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is available by default. On top right of any page, just change 'Stream' to 'Web Player'. Next time you will play a song it will play it on a web player in your browser.